# Wifi and Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: wireless

I recently updated from 23.04 to 23.10 and since then both Wifi and Bluetooth stopped working. There is no option for Wifi in the settings and I cannot turn on Bluetooth, but wired network seems to work fine.
[A screenshot from Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPdj.png) (sorry for German interface)

I have Inter Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi network controller and Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2eaj.png) of `sudo lshw -C network` if needed. And [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIrMM.png) is how my "Additional Drivers" tab looks like.

[Edit2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6oE8.png)

[Edit3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sip5.png)

[Edit4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTX40.png)

[Edit5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQNd6.png)

[Edit6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8SZK.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually there were two more drivers in the additional drivers tab right after I updated, one of which was labeled something like "unknown". I tried switching to another driver to see if this solves the issue but both of these options are unvisible since then. Thought this might help.

Comment: Are you sure you are on 23.10?  The one result show a 5.15 kernel in use and 23.10 uses 6.5.  And remove the backport iwlwifi

Comment: @Jeremy31 Directly copied from my system information : Ubuntu 23.10. I installed the repository to see if it would help. Removed it now.

Comment: Now do a reboot that the iwlwifi is gone

Comment: No change. Still getting the notification at Edit3, and no option for Wifi (see Edit4 for what I mean)

Comment: Has the result changed for `sudo dmesg|grep iwl`

Comment: @Jeremy31 It did. See Edit5.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic`  What result for `ls /lib/firmware| grep QuZ-a0-hr-b0`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Edit6

Comment: Result for `ls /boot|grep config`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Rebooted. This seems to have solved it! Both the Wifi and Bluetooth work now. Still can't explain the lag at the start though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update didn't upgrade the kernel for some reason and the older kernel didn't recognized the zstd compressed firmware files, doing `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic` got the correct kernel installed

Answer (score 0):

You need firmware! With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: Sorry. This didn't solve it. Still no Wifi and unable to turn on Bluetooth.

Comment: Each time I restart my PC it is very laggy at the start and then a there is a notification saying an update has finished. See Edit3.